# How to loops through classes and id's of two different elements efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to looping through classes that are being added and removed to an element, while also looping through hiding and showing another element. Below is the code that I have which works, but it's not ideal. How do you simplify this?

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jlw01/aj6e769k/

```js
$('.textContainer>div').hide().first().show();
$("#myImage").addClass("tint0");

$("#myButton").click(function(){
    if($("#myImage").hasClass("tint0") ){
        $("#myImage").removeClass("tint0")
        .addClass("tint1");
        $("#text0").hide()
        $("#text1").show()
    }
    else if($("#myImage").hasClass("tint1") ){
        $("#myImage").removeClass("tint1")
        .addClass("tint2");
        $("#text1").hide()
        $("#text2").show()
    }
    else if($("#myImage").hasClass("tint2")){
        $("#myImage").removeClass("tint2")
        .addClass("tint3");
        $("#text2").hide()
        $("#text3").show()
    }
    else{
        $("#myImage").removeClass("tint3")
        .addClass("tint0");
        $("#text3").hide()
        $("#text0").show()
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="myButton">&#8250;</a>

<div id="myImage">
    <svg>
      <rect id="rect1"/>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="textContainer">
  <div id="text0">
    <p>Block zero</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text1">
    <p>Block one</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text2">
    <p>Block two</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text3">
    <p>Block three</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML code.

Comment: Hi @JohnR, just added the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want or cannot change your HTML and CSS, parameterizing the repeated JavaScript code seems like the obvious way to go.

```js
$('.textContainer>div').hide().first().show();
$("#myImage").addClass("tint0");

$("#myButton").click(function(){
    for (let n = 0; n < 4; n++){
        if($("#myImage").hasClass(`tint${n}`) ){
            $("#myImage").removeClass(`tint${n}`)
            .addClass(`tint${(n + 1) % 4}`);
            $(`#text${n}`).hide();
            $(`#text${(n + 1) % 4}`).show();
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Here I used a loop with a simple counter in place of the four `if`/`else` blocks. As those only differ in the numbers of the class names and element ids, I parameterized the numbers with `${n}` and `${(n + 1) % 4}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your JavaScript code snippets as per the following idea.

1. Find the class and get the last character
2. Increment the last character value if it lesser than 3
3. Check the condition and do your work as per requirement.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/aj6e769k/1/)

**Example:**

```js
$('.textContainer>div').hide().first().show();
$("#myImage").addClass("tint0");

$("#myButton").click(function() {
  var lastChar = $("#myImage").attr("class").slice(-1),
    nxt = +lastChar < 3 ? (+lastChar) + 1 : 0;
  if ($("#myImage").hasClass("tint" + lastChar)) {
    $("#myImage").removeClass("tint" + lastChar).addClass("tint" + nxt);
    $("#text" + lastChar).hide();
    $("#text" + nxt).show();
  }
});
```

```css
#rect1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.tint0 {
  fill: orange !important;
}
.tint1 {
  fill: red !important;
}
.tint2 {
  fill: pink !important;
}
.tint3 {
  fill: purple !important;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
}
#myButton {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="myButton">&#8250;</a>

<div id="myImage">
  <svg>
      <rect id="rect1"/>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="textContainer">
  <div id="text0">
    <p>Block zero</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text1">
    <p>Block one</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text2">
    <p>Block two</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text3">
    <p>Block three</p>
  </div>
</div>
```